# Comparing two objects of System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: c#, task, equality

From my little [experiment](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bE8O44), it seems that all tasks are equal.

Is there a way to compare 2 tasks ?

In my understanding, to think about this, only way to create a duplicate task from task t1 is to make another reference to it. So, i thought that this will be easier for `Equals` to support.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var allTasks = new List<Task>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      {
          allTasks.Add(producerTask(i));
      }
      if (allTasks[0].Equals(allTasks[1]) && allTasks[0] == allTasks[1])
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Wrong tasks are equal");
      }
       var t1 = allTasks[8];
       if (!allTasks[8].Equals(t1) || !t1.Equals((allTasks[8])))
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Same tasks are not equal");
       }
      Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());
   }

   static Task producerTask(int i)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Wrong tasks are equal
```

Comment: What are trying to do, what do you expect to happen, and why

Comment: note that `Task.CompletedTask` does not create a new task. Its just a task that represents a completed task.

Comment: `==` and `Equals` for task is equivalent to reference equality check.

Comment: oh, i forgot i was returning same reference always.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary any doc for that ?

Comment: @kofifus I just checked, [in the source you can see CompletedTask property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,66f1c3e3e272f591). they say it may not always return the same instance, but it looks pretty much like a singleton instance. anyways, I think a code shouldn't rely on if it returns the same instance or not.